# Bash script not running using cronjob

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

The following is my cronjob

`* * * * * metrics.sh 5953c0685932c30ccbf7d916 5953c0e35932c30ccbf7d917`

And here is my metrics.sh

```
d_t=$(df | grep "/$" | awk '{print $2;}')
d_u=$(df | grep "/$" | awk '{print $3;}')
m_t=$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $2;}')
m_u=$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3;}')
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"d_t":'$d_t',"d_u":'$d_u',"m_t":'$m_t',"m_u":'$m_u'}' https://localhost:3000/server/metrics/$1/$2
```

Comment: Put the full path name in front of `metrics.sh`. Also you aren't specifying when `cron` should run the job. How often do you want it to run?

Comment: I want the cron to run every minute hence I have put 5 stars and the path where metrics.sh resides is actually in a directory outside root. So basically cd /directory/metrics.sh

Comment: Don't put in the `cd` just the full path i.e.:`/user/local/bin/metrics.sh`. Let me know if that fixes it and I'll post a proper answer for others to see.

Answer (score 3):

metrics.sh must be executable from a CLI as a first step in troubleshooting your issue.  Common failure causes is the script not being executable or a coding mistake in the script.

```
ls -l metrics.sh
```

Should have the x flag set for the correct owner, group or world.

```
./metrics.sh
```

Should run error free or will provide error messages that indicate coding or privilege problems.

Cron jobs run more reliably when using fully qualified directives and not assuming that all variables will be passed to cron.  ex:

```
* * * * * $HOME/metrics.sh
```

or

```
* * * * * /home/user/scripts/metrics.sh
```

Your script is elegant and I see no obvious programming errors.  However, note that bash scripts should have the following first line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```